# Windows Forms C#: Stackoverflow or Youtube tags-like textbox, is this possible

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm trying to write a Windows Forms desktop application in C# and I want the user to be able to write in words or sentences, separated with for example a comma, that will create a deleteable(with a small 'x') "object"(for lack of a better word) for each comma-separated item. See image [Youtube tags textbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXJyV.jpg)

Real world examples are the Stackoverflow tags textbox or the Youtube tags-textbox. Is this possible in Windows Forms and if so, how?

Thank you!

Ps. I'm sorry if this has been asked but I tried to search for it but I didn't really know what to search for.

Comment: I don't think WInforms Textbox supports anything like that

Comment: There's no control that will do this for you by default, you would either have to build it yourself of use a third party component. So that makes this question off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe take a look if SyncFusion has a feature you can use, they even have a community licence which might work for you.

Comment: You surely can write this yourself; you did mention all the ingredients; use a nice Button class and a FlowLayoutPanel..